# Typescript does not copy d.ts files to build

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, .d.ts

So maybe I'm confused, but I thought that if I added `declaration:true` to my tsconfig.json I could have it tsc copy my `*.d.ts` files, along side the transpiled code & it's `d.ts` files?

EG:

```
- src
 - lib
   - types.d.ts
   - foo.ts
```

I would expect the result of tsc to be something like:

```
- build
 - lib
   - types.d.ts
   - foo.js
   - foo.d.ts
```

However, I can't seem to get `types.d.ts` to be copied to my build directory.

Does typescript not provide any mechanism to copy `.d.ts` files?  Or do I just have a misconfiguration somewhere? (I've tried a lot of different configurations at this point; nothing seems to work)

Comment: seems like `declaration:true` ONLY refers to creating declarations from `.ts` files... Still seems super odd there isn't some way to easily copy my ambient .d.ts files over to the build

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You are right - `declaration:true` implies that only for each given `.ts` file `tsc` generates and copies a corresponding `.d.ts` output file to the `build` directory  (in addition to `.js` and `.map` if applicable). So `tsc` will not copy your custom `types.d.ts` file to the output directory.

Basically `.d.ts` files are seen as untouchable input for the compiler to do type checks. They are not used for any output generation, which also means, they do not get copied over to `build`. You can read more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5112) about the maintainers' standpoint:

> The .d.ts files you use are an input to the build system but not an output. It's perfectly reasonable to consume some types from a .d.ts but have your output not use those types, so there'd be no reason to distribute the input .d.ts with your build results. [...] It sounds like you'll want a post-build step in your build tool to copy the relevant .d.ts files wherever you need them.
>
> The .d.ts files are considered "references" the compiler will not touch them, not move them, or recreate them. An easy way to think of the .d.ts files is that they go along with your .js files. if you are copying the .js files, you should copy the matching .d.ts.

#### Solution #1: Copy d.ts files via manual build step

A possible solution is to copy all needed `.d.ts` files like `types.d.ts` manually in a build step. The concrete tool is preference and dependents on your project and build type, OS amongst others. This tool should preserve the directory structure under `src` when copying files to `build`, so that `import` type references still work. To name a few: [`cp --parents`](https://serverfault.com/questions/180853/how-to-copy-file-preserving-directory-path-in-linux) (shell), `rsync`, `robocopy` or a platform independent npm package like [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles):

```
"scripts": {
  "copy-dts": "copyfiles -u 1 \"src/**/*.d.ts\" build"
}
```

#### Solution #2: Reword d.ts files to .ts extension

Reword your `.d.ts` files to `.ts` extension (or re-integrate the types into existent `.ts` files), so `tsc` takes care of emitting the declarations in the output. Slight disadvantage: You have no compiler enforced separation between types and implementation code (`d.ts` files are not allowed to contain code). Big advantage is, you don't need an additional build step.

In my opinion, the latter is the easiest approach to generate a public API e.g. for your npm package, whereas a `.d.ts` file could make a candidate for an internally used and shared type declaration.

Comment: my approach has just been to instead write my global types in a `.ts` file... Do you see any downside to doing it this way?

Comment: @NSjonas updated my answer to also refer to your approach with `.ts` files for types.

Comment: Worth mentioning -  Solution #2 will also result in an empty js file created by the compiler...

Comment: Sad that this is the current workaround. Super annoying to deal with for generated protobufs

Answer (score 1):

Use [package.json "files" field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files) to include type definition files. Your type definitions will not get copied to the build directory, but the resulting package will still include them.

```json
"files": [
    "build",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

The generated type declaration files will automatically maintain any references to the global declaration file.

```
/// <reference path="../src/types.d.ts" />
```