# .d.ts file not included for nested file exporting types

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am using webpack and awesome-typescript-loader to bundle my project and create .d.ts files. I have a structure like this:

```
src
  - main.ts
  - types
    - index.ts
    - SomeType.ts
```

in main.ts I am exporting everything:

```
export * from './types';
export default ...
```

and types/index.ts looks like:

```
export * from './SomeType.ts';
```

Everything in the types folder is missing when I build the project, but I would expect .d.ts files to be created so I can import those types in other projects.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "reportFiles": ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your types folder only contain type declarations and no implementations? .d.ts files in `src` are not considered by TypeScript to be copied to `build` folder, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018167/typescript-does-not-copy-d-ts-files-to-build). But  awesome-typescript-loader emits .d.ts files from your .ts files with code, when you have "declaration": true.

Comment: I haven't created any .d.ts files myself, but the files in the type files are all .ts files. There are only types defined within those files that I import into my project. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awesome-typescript-loader seems to behave differently from ts-loader and `tsc` regarding the  emission of declarations from `ts` files with only contained type declarations.

Given a file `types.ts` with only a type export

```
export type MyType = "a"
```

and an import in another module `index.ts`

```
import { MyType } from "./types";
```

`tsc` and `ts-loader` both emit a `types.d.ts` file containing the type, but not awesome-typescript-loader. I cannot tell you the exact reason here - the only reference I found is that awesome-ts-loaders seemingly [tries to be more intelligent](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/94) based on more sophisticated dependency resolution approach, which could backfire in this edge case. When in doubt, I would assume `tsc` to have the correct reference behavior.

Anyway, it is more idiomatic to rename `ts` files with only type declarations to `d.ts` extension, as no code output is emitted. So you end up with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018167/typescript-does-not-copy-d-ts-files-to-build), why d.ts files from a source directory are not copied to a build folder by `tsc`.

The easiest way for you in this case would be to manually copy the needed d.ts files (for a public library API or similar) to `dist` via a manual build step. Or you can use the new babel typescript preset with Webpack and have a separate `tsc` compilation step only for declarations.

Comment: Great answer. I ended up ditching awesome-typescript-loader, using tsc from the command line with `--emitDeclarationOnly` to output my .d.ts files from my entire project and am using babel typescript loader with webpack to compiler the files.