# How to publish multiple .d.ts files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a package where the `src` with the following structure:

```
┌────────┐     ┌───────┐   
│moduleA │─┬── │code.ts│   
└────────┘ │   └───────┘   
           │   ┌──────────┐
           ├── │code.d.ts │
           │   └──────────┘
           │   ┌──────────┐
           └── │types.d.ts│
               └──────────┘
```

where the `code.d.ts` has the definitions of the exports of `code.ts` and `types.d.ts` hold a `namespace`for the types used in `code.d.ts`. This works well in the package but when I export it the namespace is not recognized in the `code.d.ts` file anymore. Also every article about how to export types is quite confusing. Can someone point me into a direction where to start figuring this out.

**`code.ts`**

```
export default class MyClass {
    createSubject(id: string): Promise<MyNamespace.Subject> {
        return this.put(`/subjects/${id}`)
    }
```

**`code.d.ts`**

```
export default class MyClass {
    createSubject(id: string): Promise<MyNamespace.Subject>
```

**`type.d.ts`**

```
declare namespace MyNamespace { 
  export interface Subject {
   id: String
  }
}
```

The code is auto generated from openAPI files, so `type.d.ts` just represent the types from the openAPI file and `code.ts` is a simple class with a method for every existing endpoint.

Comment: A code sample would clarify your issue at-hand a bit better. My guess is 1) `code.ts` takes priority over `code.d.ts` (rename one of those), 2) `d.ts` files are only seen as compilation input and not emitted (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018167/typescript-does-not-copy-d-ts-files-to-build/56440335#56440335) for a related answer)

Comment: @ford04 added some code hopefully its more clear now