# Export extended express request in typescript library

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a library which extends the `express` `Response` with a property `warn()` and when using the library I want to have the new property `warn()` available.

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "types": ["mocha"],
    "typeRoots": ["@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"]
}
```

This is my `@types/express/index.d.ts`:

```js
import * as express from 'express'
import http from 'http'

export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Response<ResBody = any>
      extends http.ServerResponse,
        express.Response {
      warn(): this
    }
  }
}
```

`src/registerwarn.ts`:

```js
export function registerwarn() {
  return (_req: Request, res: Express.Response, next): void => {
    res.warn = (): Express.Response => {
      console.log("warning");
      return res;
    };
    return next();
  };
}
```

`src/warnings.ts`:

```js
import { registerwarn } from './registerwarn'
export default [registerwarn()]
```

A test:

`test/warningtest.ts`:

```js
import 'should'
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import warnings from '../src/warnings'

describe('test', (): void => {
  const app = express()
  app.use(warnings)
  app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.status(200).warn().send({ some: 'content' })
  })
  it('should ', (done) => {
    done()
  })
})
```

Running `tsc` returns these errors:

```sh
src/registerwarn.ts:3:9 - error TS2339: Property 'warn' does not exist on type 'Response'.

     res.warn = (): Express.Response => {
         ~~~~

test/hello_tests.ts:9:21 - error TS2339: Property 'warn' does not exist on type 'Response<any>'.

     res.status(200).warn().send({ some: 'content' })
                     ~~~~


Found 2 errors.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How can I get rid of these errors and make sure if somebody uses the library from `npm` doesn't get these warnings as well?

I created a repro [here](https://github.com/AlexZeitler/so-ts-extend-repro).

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here I have identified, although I am unable to comment whether this is the "best" solution available - these are merely what I came up with.

### Solution I (recommended): Remove `mocha` from globally declared `types` in `tsconfig.json`

As per the [documentation on `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions.types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types), declaring `mocha` under `types` will significantly restrict the visibility of `@types` packages.

> By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible. For example, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included in the global scope. For instance:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "types": ["node", "jest", "express"]
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This tsconfig.json file will only include ./node_modules/@types/node, ./node_modules/@types/jest and ./node_modules/@types/express. Other packages under node_modules/@types/* will not be included.

By dropping the `compilerOptions.types` flag altogether, your typing should now be visible.

Within your test file, you should now add an import line for `import 'mocha'` to gain access to testing methods (e.g. `describe`, `it`, etc). This will need to be done for each test. I would recommend using an import, as it is a bit clearer where your declarations are coming from (and not invisibly popping up as a result of your `tsconfig.json`).

Additionally, I am not sure that you would want `mocha` to be declared globally here either, as `mocha` test imports would automatically be visible under files in the `src` folder. I suspect you might run into some other strange errors using this flag.

> Note: I suppose you could alternative double-down with the `types` flag and add `"express"` to this list, which will locate your module augmentation under `@types`. Your mileage may vary significantly with this flag.

### Solution II: Explicitly add your `@types` `.d.ts` declarations under the `include` field.

By specifying the `compilerOptions.types` flag, visibility is now removed from your custom `@types` directory. You can hack this back in by modifying the `include` flag from

```
"include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"]
```

to

```
"include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*", "@types/**/*.d.ts"]
```

I am not too keen on this solution, as it does not address the underlying cause of `@types` not being visible. You may experience strange errors with this route.

---

After choosing a solution above (or possibly finding an alternative solution), you need to resolve a few typing errors in the project:

- The typings for your warnings sources does not seem to be compatible with any `app.use` overload. `tests/hello_tests.ts` is complaining about no matching type overload for `app.use(warnings)`.
- You do not need to specify any `extends` for your `Response` interface - all interfaces under the same namespace will be merged. Since you are declaring an extends on `express.Response`, the same interface you are augmenting and merging, the interface declaration is now recursively referencing itself and causing an error: `Type 'Response<ResBody>' recursively references itself as a base type.`. Dropping this `extends` clause resolves this error and preserves the functionality you desire.

  ```
  declare global {
    namespace Express {
      export interface Response<ResBody = any> {
        warn(): this
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  > Note that I preserved the generic in this instance, but it is optional. If any of your new functionalities require the generic, you should specify it (as demonstrated above).

After these typing issues are resolved, `tsc` exits successfully and reports no errors.

---

As an aside that is unrelated to your question, your `prettier` configuration is having a field day with `CRLF`/`\r\n` line endings (i.e. an error on every line). You should [configure your configuration to be more relaxed](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), or [specify a `.gitattributes` file in your Git repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) so that line endings are `LF`/`\n` (and not `CRLF`/`\r\n`) by default on checkout.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I tried solution 1 and it seems to work in general. When using the library from another project, yet I have to manually add the `@types/express/index.d.ts`.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler When compiling your TypeScript project, `.d.ts` files and "external" library types (e.g. `.d.ts` typings from `compilerOptions.typeRoots`) are *not* bundled into your library's outputted `.d.ts` module typings. You may need to move your Express.js module augmentation within your project sources (e.g. `src`) and use a `.ts` extensions instead (as `.d.ts` typings are *not* bundled) to be able to recognize these types in another project. You could alternatively just copy the `@types/express/index.d.ts` into your transpiled output directory after TypeScript compilation.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Take a look into this StackOverflow post about the behavior of the TypeScript compiler with `.d.ts` files in your project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440335/14352161

Comment: Thanks again, you helped me a lot.