# Angular Library 11: include index.d.ts in build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-library, angular-devkit

I want to create typings for my library which uses an external API from `<script>`. If I build the library (`ng build angular8-yandex-maps --prod`) everything is ok but when I try to import the built library in the Angular app, it fails - `Cannot find namespace 'ymaps'`, `Cannot find type definition file for 'yandex-maps'` etc.

Declared namespace isn't included in the build, is it possible to include it?

`dist/**/*.component.d.ts`

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'yandex-maps'
/// <reference types="yandex-maps" />
```

## Reproduction

#### typings/yandex-maps/index.d.ts

```
declare namespace ymaps {
  ...
}
```

#### tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": ["yandex-maps"],
    "typeRoots": ["../../node_modules/@types", "src/lib/typings"],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.d.ts` will not be copied, you should use `.ts` instead + add `<reference />` in `public-api.ts`. As a result compiler will create `dist/**/typings/yandex-maps/index.d.ts` and `<reference />` in `public-api.d.ts`.

Some further information: [Typescript does not copy d.ts files to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018167/typescript-does-not-copy-d-ts-files-to-build)

#### tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2018"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

#### typings/yandex-maps/index.ts

```
declare namespace {
  ...
}
```

#### public-api.ts

```
// <reference path="./lib/typings/yandex-maps/index.ts" />
```

#### UPD:

ESLint: Do not use a triple slash reference for ./lib/typings/yandex-maps/index.ts, use `import` style instead.(@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference)

```
import './lib/typings/yandex-maps/index';
```