# AWS Code Build Cannot Traverse CDK Project Folder Structure For TypeScript Types

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

**Error on AWS Code Build:** `lib/lambda-Stacks/cognito-triggers-Stack.ts(4,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../src/types/types' or its corresponding type declarations.`

**Desired Outcome:** For the Code Build to build the CDK Project successfully and update the Cloud Formation Stacks.

**CDK Pipeline Configuration:**

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-pipeline-${appName}`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-pipeline-${appName}`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment),
    installCommands: ["npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g aws-cdk"],
    commands: ["cd backend", "npm ci", "npm run build", "npx cdk synth"],
    primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5112), I changed the `.d.ts` extension to `.ts` for the easiest solution.

[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018167/typescript-does-not-copy-d-ts-files-to-build) about more generically building with typescript.d.ts files